# How should be implemented the ViewModel for an activity with many fields

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

## Problem

There is a settings screen (`SettingsActivity`) with about 10 text fields and 3 buttons. The text fields, which on `onClick` open a dialog to insert/edit text, has its contents saved in the `SharedPreferences`. The buttons do async requests to retrieve contents and save elsewhere. During the requests, a dialog is shown to notify the progress.

## Initial solution

#### DataRepository

Basically a wrapper for the SharedPreferences that has 10 getters and 10 setters, one for each field. On `get[field_name]`, the `DataRepository` gets the value from the `SharedPreferences` and on `set[field_name]`, it commits to the `SharedPreferences`.

#### ViewModel

A `ViewModel` which has 10 `MutableLiveData` objects, one for each field. This class implements the `LifecycleObserver` to know about the `SettingsActivity` lifecycle so it could load the fields from the repository on `onCreate` and save the fields to the repository on `onDestroy`.

There are also 3 methods to do the 3 async requests that are fired by the 3 buttons mentioned. Each method receives an `OnRequestProgressListener` instance, that is passed to the class that makes the async request to be used to notify the view about the progress.

#### View

An activity with 10 fields, that observes the 10 `MutableLiveData` from the `ViewModel`. On `onClick` of each field, a dialog is opened to edit/insert text. On the `onPositiveButton` of the dialog, the observer of the corresponding field is called.

The activity implements the `OnRequestProgressListener` to show and hide dialogs accordingly to the async requests progress.

## Initial solution problem

The design described above doesn't seem to be correct. I can point out some:

- 10 `MutableLiveData` in the `ViewModel`;
- 10 getters and 10 setters in the `DataRepository`;
- A repository for `SharedPreferences`.
- The `ViewModel` receives listeners to pass to the classes that do the async requests which use these listeners to notify the view. All with the `ViewModel` in the middle.

## Correct solution

Is that the correct solution? If not, which I believe it isn't, how should be designed the correct solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - 10 MutableLiveData in the ViewModel;

That's totally fine, if you have 10 independent pieces of data you can have a LiveData for each one.

> - A repository for SharedPreferences.

Repository should be an abstraction over your data layer, allowing you to easily switch implementations. So having a repository over shared preferences is ok in theory.

But in your case, if the only thing the repository does is forwarding calls to `SharedPreferences` since the probability of switching storage solution from shared prefs to something else is very low, I would get rid of the repository and use SharedPreferences directly to simplify the code.

> - 10 getters and 10 setters in the DataRepository;

Same here, if you have 10 pieces of data stored in you class and want it to be accessible from outside you should use the property pattern, that results in a getter and setter in Java. In Kotlin though you won't need to write getters and setters explicitly.
Also, if you decide to remove DataRepository you won't need that code.

> - The ViewModel receives listeners to pass to the classes that do the async requests which use these listeners to notify the view. All with the ViewModel in the middle.

This one sounds a bit wrong, if you create a listener in your activity chances are that you'll accidentally use the anonymous class that has a reference to activity, pass it to the `ViewModel` and get a memory leak.
You should not pass activity reference to the `ViewModel`.
The correct way of communication is through LiveData. You need to create a LiveData that will post progress, use it inside the ViewModel, providing it with the progress and your activity needs to subscribe to it to get the progress information.
With this approach, you'll be safe from memory leaks.

Comment: About the `LiveData` to post progress: I created a method in the `ViewModel` to fetch some data. The method returns a `LiveData`, so when the `Activity` needs that data, it calls the method and subscribes. When the `LiveData`'s value is `null`, a `Dialog` is shown; when the value is true or false, the fetch succeeded or failed, so a new `Dialog` notifies this state. What do you think about the need for the `Activity` to unsubscribe the `LiveData`? I really need to keep a reference to the `LiveData` returned by the method so I can unsubscribe later when the request succeeds or fails?

Comment: You don't need to ubsubscribe from LiveData, it is designed to handle unsubscription by itself. When you call `.observe` you provide the lyfecycle owner, based on which it will unsubscribe. So if you provide your activity as lifecycle owner, LiveData will unsibscribe automatically when your activity is destroyed.

Comment: But when the user clicks the button again, another instance of `LiveData` is returned for the new request. Won't there be N `LiveData` instances in the Nth time the button is clicked? Maybe if the activity unsubscribe the `LiveData`, there won't be anything else holding the instance, so it could be destroyed by the garbage collector. I consider there won't be an N > 3 if the user is a normal person, but I'm afraid it can be a bad design. (Thanks for your help!)

Comment: Oh, that's not a corret way to work with LiveData. You need one live data for you data source - dialog info. You create the live data in the ViewModel once and then call `setValue` when data changes. In the Activity you call `.observe(this, observer)` once too and handle the results from ViewModel in the observer. In your case when button is pressed you'll call a method in ViewModel, ViewModel will process something and call .setValue on LiveData and in your activity the observer will get new data, based on that you'll show or hide your dialog. Please read official docs for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can use one `Settings` data class that contains Strings, integers and getters that encapsulates your data.

One `MutableLiveData<Settings>` is enough to keep track of changes and pass changes to UI. And with data-binding you also won't need boilerplate code if you are using TextViews and EditTexts. For data binding to work with `LiveData` you need to invoke `setValue()` of `LiveData` using a method defined in `ViewModel`. I made [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288066/how-can-i-do-databinding-with-livedata/51288791#51288791) how data-binding works and does not work with `LiveData`.

You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288791/5457853) for how you can work with `LiveData` with mutable objects and update UI without any boiler code and unnecessary MutableLiveDatas or transforming `MutableLiveData<Object>` to `MutableLiveData<String>` or `MutableLiveData<Integer>`.

If you can share your layout file i can post more specific answer.