# Two-way data binding between EditText and custom class field

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata, two-way-binding

I have a custom class names `FormData` that store four String fields. In set() method of each field, I call trim() function on that field. I create a MutableLiveData and put an instance of `FormData` in it in my ViewModel. I created four EditText and set two-way binding in the layout file for each field (ex. `android:text="@={formData.firstName}"`). I see that values are retrieved from the EditText, trimmed and stored in the related field in the `FormData` instance. However, EditText is not updated, the untrimmed text is still there. How can I achieve a successful two-way binding in this manner? Google's classic vanilla examples are of course not helpful as usual.

Answer (score 0):

For 2-way binding to work on UI, you need to use `setValue()` method for `LiveData`. I had made an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51288791/5457853) about this.

Comment: Like assigning it to itself after changes, i.e. `formData.value = formData.value`?

Comment: For UI to change after setting data of LiveData is to call `setValue()` method. You can use that either. You also need to set life cycle owner, i think you are using it already, `dataBinding.setLifeCycleOwner()`. If your 2-way data binding works after you rotate your phone that means you should call `setValue()` to make it work it without rotating your phone.